# C# Unity: Enter the sub values ​of the class with a "partial name+number"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I retrieved the number from a class.
now I would like to enter the options through the latter:

```
float CarLevel = Settings.LevelSelected; // from main get the level

var LevelNumber = Settings.(LevelOfCar+CarLevel); //enter in corret level

float Kmh = LevelNumber.Kmh; //get the par of level
```

obviously it doesn't work like this ... how can I do to avoid a big classic IF LEVEL IS 2 ELSE .... for all levels? tips?

Comment: Use a `Dictionary`?

Comment: Do you know that I don't understand them well? Can you give me an example about the case? If you don't mind a lot of time, of course.

Comment: So, the properties are named `LevelOfCar1`, `LevelOfCar2` etc, right?

Comment: yes, they are called this way (however it will be name1 2 3 4 5, the mechanism is that)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a more object oriented approach.

Consider the following

```
public class Level : ScriptableObject
{
    public int CarLevel;
    public float Kmh;
    // other variables that are shared across all levels
}
```

And if you need specific code for each level which share the same script, you could use inheritance.

```
public class SpecificLevel : Level
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {

    }
}
```

Have a manager class containing all your levels.

```
public class LevelManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Assign levels here through the inspector
    public List<Level> Levels;

    public void LoadLevel()
    {
        Level level = Levels.First(x => x.CarLevel == Settings.LevelSelected);
        // Do whatever you want with your level
    } 
}
```

You will need to add the linq using.

```
using System.Linq;
```

If you do not know about scriptable objects, i suggest following [this](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/live-sessions-on-scripting) short tutorial. It will help you out greatly in your development.

Comment: (looks like I've disappeared but I'm studying the case .... I update the post as soon as I finish experimenting) I will surely return to XD soon